# Is there a way to find all the Log.d() lines in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

- I have used many logs in project which i want to remove
- Is there a way to find all the `Log.d()` lines in android studio using
  a find method

Comment: right click the function => is there a context menu entry called "find usage of"?

Comment: also, why remove logs?! wouldn't adapting the log-level be better?

Answer (score 7):

1. Bring up "Find in Path" using `Edit > Find > Find In Path...` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)
2. Search for `Log.d` in the search box. You can limit the files to search for using the `File mask` option in the top right e.g. to limit your search to `.java` files.
3. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. This will now show your results in the Search panel.

Alternatively, use an alternative logging library such as [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) that won't dump out debug logs in user builds.

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> and then type in `"Log.d(",` that will show you the places where it's being used.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing all `Log.d()` calls manually you can edit your `proguard-rules.pro` file to include the following lines:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

It will make the functions `Log.d()` and `Log.v()` empty, generating no logs in your release apk.